# Using a small lookup table in a GLSL shader

Tags: arrays, vector, glsl, lookup

I have a fragment shader and I would like to build a small loookup table and interpolate on it. My current code is this (sorry for the verbosity):

```
float inverse_f(float r)
{

    // Build a lookup table on the radius, as a fixed-size table.
    // We will use a vec3 since we will store the multipled number in the Z coordinate.
    // So to recap: x will be the radius, y will be the f(x) distortion, and Z will be x * y;
    vec3[32] lut;

    // Flame has no overflow bbox so we can safely max out at the image edge, plus some cushion
    float max_r = sqrt((adsk_input1_aspect * adsk_input1_aspect) + 1) + 0.1;
    float incr = max_r / 32;
    float lut_r = 0;
    float f;
    for(int i=0; i < 32; i++) {
        f = distortion_f(lut_r);
        lut[i] = vec3(lut_r, f, lut_r * f);
        lut_r += incr;
    }

    float df;
    float dz;
    float t;

    // Now find the nehgbouring elements
    for(int i=0; i < 32; i++) {
        if(lut[i].z < r) {
            // found!
            df = lut[i+1].y - lut[i].y;
            dz = lut[i+1].z - lut[i].z;
            t = (r - lut[i].z) / dz;
            return df * t;
        }
    }
}
```

I am working with #version 120. However it's not working (all the iterations where this function is called return the same value). So either I am doing something wrong with the array (it's getting filled with the same values) or the return from the for loop does not work because the loop gets unrolled in some way that I don't understand. Is there something that springs to mind that could cause this behavior (the same value returned independently of the passed-in R value)?

Comment: What exactly is happening that is contrary to what you expect (and what do you expect?)  What driver/OpenGL version are you using and what hardware/software for rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out I made 3 mistakes here.

First, I need to find both elements to interpolate between them, so the condition needs to be

```
 lut[i].z > r && lut[i-1].z < r
```

Secondly, I made a mistake in the linear interpolation since I need to add the initial value of the left tuple to the result.

And, as the last bummer, one of the uniforms was named wrong so it defaulted to 0, breaking the computation. The final version (more or less) is this:

```
float inverse_f(float r)
{

    // Build a lookup table on the radius, as a fixed-size table.
    // We will use a vec3 since we will store the multipled number in the Z coordinate.
    // So to recap: x will be the radius, y will be the f(x) distortion, and Z will be x * y;
    vec3[32] lut;

    // Flame has no overflow bbox so we can safely max out at the image edge, plus some cushion
    float max_r = sqrt((adsk_input1_frameratio * adsk_input1_frameratio) + 1) + 1;
    float incr = max_r / 32;
    float lut_r = 0;
    float f;
    for(int i=0; i < 32; i++) {
        f = distortion_f(lut_r);
        lut[i] = vec3(lut_r, f, lut_r * f);
        lut_r += incr;
    }

    float df;
    float dr;
    float t;

    // Now find the nehgbouring elements
    for(int i=0; i < 32; i++) {
        if(lut[i].z > r && lut[i-1].z < r) {
            // found!
            df = lut[i+1].y - lut[i].y;
            dr = lut[i+1].z - lut[i].z;
            t = (r - lut[i].z) / dr;
            return lut[i].y + (df * t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks like it should work, though if the lookup table is entirely uniform (adsk_input1_frameratio is a uniform var and distortion_f doesn't read any varyings), then you're much better off computing the lut on the CPU and making it a uniform array that you compute once when you set uniforms.

Comment: I really want to do that but I don't have access to the CPU part of the system - I can only load a shader. And I cannot do a for loop when defining a uniform.